# How to estimate isoperimetric constant?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Suppose $(X^m, g)$ is a closed Riemannian manifold of dimension $m$ with the following properties,

1. There is a constant $\kappa$ such that $\kappa r^m \leq Vol(B(x, r)) \leq \kappa^{-1} r^m$
   for every $r \in (0,1)$.
2. For every $C^1$ function $f$, we have
   $(\int_X |f|^{\frac{2m}{m-2}})^{\frac{m-2}{m}} \leq C_S (\int_X |f|^2 + |\nabla f|^2)$.
3. For every $C^1$ function $f$, we have
   $\int_X |f|^2 \leq C_P (\int_X |\nabla f|^2 + (\int_X f)^2)$.

Can we say that there is a positive constant $I$ depending only on $m, \kappa, C_S, C_P$ such that $\frac{Area(\partial \Omega)^m}{Vol(\Omega)^{m-1}} \geq I$ for every domain $\Omega$
satisfying $Vol(\Omega) \leq \frac{1}{2} Vol(X)$?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask

Comment: :), in case it wasn't clear.

Comment: I agree with David. This is potentially an interesting question, but it really needs to be stated more precisely and in more detail.

Comment: I modified the problem. Now it should be clear.

Comment: I'm curious, you used the PDE tag, was there a specific PDE that motivated this? Am I right in the assumption that it was Ricci-Flow?

Comment: But I'm not sure whether there are any experts on this active on MO. Have you asked any experts on the subject of Sobolev and isoperimetric inequalities?

Comment: In 3) you forgot to add the assumption $\int_X f=0$.

Comment: I added a term in condition 3).     

Comment: It is worth noting that this is essentially the same as asking whether the $L_2$ Sobolev constant determines a bound on the $L_1$ Sobolev constant. It is well known how to go in the opposite direction, but I don't believe I've ever seen any result in this direction. On the other hand, I don't believe I've seen any counterexample, either.

Comment: If X is a Fano manifold and g is a Kahler metric evolving under the normalized Kahler-Ricci flow, then 1),2),3) hold for all positive time with uniform constants. 

On the other hand the only case I know (of KRF on Fanos) where the isoperimetric constant can be bounded is when the complex dimension is 2, http://arxiv.org/abs/0902.1545

My guess is that this was the motivation of the OP.

Comment: Yes, this is one motivation.   Thanks for the suggestion of Deane Yang. However, I'm not familiar with any experts on isoperimetric constant.

Comment: I would add that it is not clear to me whether just #2 alone could imply a bound on the isoperimetric constant. Or is that known to be false?

Comment: At least I don't know if #2 alone can imply isoperimetric constant.

Comment: It is false that just #2 implies a bound on the isoperimetric constant. For an example, take an analytic family of projective varieties X_t (parametrized by t a disc in C, with the whole family embedded in CxP^N) which are smooth for t not 0, while X_0 is reducible with at least 2 components. Take as Kahler metrics the restriction of the Fubini-Study metric to X_t. Then these metrics as t goes to 0 have uniform Sobolev constant (by Michael-Simon, Allard), but the Poincare' constant goes to infinity (by Yoshikawa, see e.g. arXiv:0905.3424 remark on p.24). There are surely simpler examples...
 